# scrollintoview won't fire on resize

Tags: javascript, resize

I have a full screen slider, for which I'm using scrollintoview on resize to keep the current slide centered in the viewport but for some reason scrollintoview does not fire on resize in safari?

Scrollintoview works on a click function but when I attempt to trigger it inside my resize function it fails to fire?

Am I missing something?

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
 resize();
});;

function resize(){

var active_slide = $('.active').attr('id');
document.getElementById(active_slide).scrollIntoView();
```

}

Edit - scrollintoview works when I don't use a variable in getElementById i.e.

Works - document.getElementById('WI-slide2').scrollIntoView();

Does not work - document.getElementById(active_slide).scrollIntoView();

Comment: Could you please show some code, and make a http://jsfiddle.net, if possible?

Comment: http://dev.wickedaudio.com/

Answer (score 0):

I tried this which worked fine on Safari 6.1.1:

```
<script>

window.onresize = function(event) {
var e = document.getElementById("theElement");
e.scrollIntoView(true);
};

</script>
```

It is not clear to my why that wouldn't work for you... have you tried deferring the scrollIntoView into a timer like this ? :

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
window.setTimeout(resize,1000);

};
```

Comment: Nathan White: I don't got enough reputation to directly comment under your post, so: you should probably log (i.e. console.log(active_slide)) and make sure you are getting the correct element id.